# Redis on windows installation failed

Tags: windows, redis

I am trying to install **Redis 3.2.100** from .msi file from here https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases , but I am getting error

> redis on windows setup wizard ended prematurely.

I am using windows 7, What can I do to install Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed windows update and restart system,after that installation worked for me.

Comment: For me, only system restart was enough.